# How to put Camera component under transparent React Navigator Header?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

I'm currently trying to put my Camera component under a transparent React Navigator header.

I've tried display type, position type, custom Header style, nothing seems to work. Any tips?

```
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{
            headerStyle: {
              position: 'fixed',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            }
          }}
         />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

The `<Home/>` component just returns a  component for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question lol. For anyone who encounters the same issue, change above to:

```
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{
            headerTransparent: true
          }}
         />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

And react navigation library will handle it all for you